# Vue warn : the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm testing 'v-runtime-template' component in App.vue which made by Vue-Cli enviornment.

And there is some problems...

[Imgur1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHNRj.png)

It seems that `v-runtime-template` component couldn't render my html syntax :,(

But, Look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-runtime-template-jbpyo?fontsize=14) example, this example rendered perfectly my html syntax
 `<button @click="func()">asdf</button>` unlike my `App.vue`.

I only rewrote `App.vue` and installed `v-runtime-template` perfectly, and the other files are same initial statement when `vue create` worked.

---

- **So I wonder if `v-runtime-template` can't work in vue-cli enviorment.**
- **First of all, I wonder what is the cause too.**

  ---

Thank you

**App.vue**

This is the file which i made using `vue create` in `vue-cli`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-runtime-template :template="template"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";
import Vue from 'vue';
export default {
  components:{
    VRuntimeTemplate
  },

  data: () => ({
    template: `
      <button @click="func()">asdf</button>
    `
  }),
  name: 'app',
  methods:{
    func(){
      alert('hi');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

---

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

What I want is that `<button @click="func()">asdf</button>` or any other tags work perfectly using `v-runtime-template` !

plz share your tips! :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, as the error noted, you can't use the runtime build to compile Single File Components

Comment: Assuming this is Vue CLI 3, try running `vue ui` and then edit the settings of your project to `Enable runtime compiler`. If you don't want to go through the UI you can set it in the config yourself, see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler. For more background see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

Comment: Relevant docs from `v-runtime-template`: https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template#getting-started

Comment: @skirtle this is correct tips ~ ! thx :)

Comment: @CaddyDZ thanks too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@skirtle Answer correctly ! thank you :)

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@vue/app'
    ],
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: "vue/dist/vue.common",
            },
        },
    },
    // vue 
}
```